# Rewrite the following loop (java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a total beginner in the field of programming. I have worked with the basics, but I have no clue on how to do the following:

Rewrite the following loop, using the enhanced for loop construct. Here, values is an array of floating-point numbers.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { total = total + values[i]; }
```

Comment: Do you know what an enhanced for loop is?

Comment: If i recall correctly, an enhanced for loop is used when you want to visit all elements of an array. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you try to search google for "enhanced for loop"?

Answer (score 4):

The [enhanced `for-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) is also called a `for-each` loop. It might be done like

```
for (float value : values) { // <-- for each value in values
    total += value; // <-- add the value to the total.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for (float f : values) { total+= f; }

Answer (score 0):

Use enhanced for-loop

```
for (float value : values) { 
total += value; 
}
```

If you like you can look at this tutorial to learn more:  http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/24-java-lang/480-the-enhanced-for-loop.html